# F3 routing engine works using XAMPP and PhpStorm on Linux, but gives 404 for CSS files

Tags: css, phpstorm, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to code a F3 ("Fat Free Framework") application using PhpStorm and XAMPP on Linux.

<strike>In order to make use of the .htaccess file provided by F3 necessary for the RewriteEngine</strike> (see the comments as why this is wrong), I launch my code using the following special run configuration :

[image: Edit run/debug configurations menu from PhpStorm]

I launch the run configuration, which starts the Web Server. I open a browser and go to http://localhost:8000/ . I can see the content, and the links work and I can navigate from page to page, per the routes defined.

But none of the CSS is there. If I click on "view-source" and click on the CSS link, I get the 404 Not Found message from F3. So, it seems that for some reason, F3 is blocking CSS files.

The beginning of the webpage is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>A title</title>
    <link href="{{@BASE}}/f3style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Although the @BASE variable is empty in my case. The "f3style.css" file is really at the root of my web directory currently.

<strike>I use the default .htaccess file recommended by F3:</strike>

```
RewriteEngine On

# Uncommenting the following line has no effect
# RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(app|tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

(Again, see the comments as to why the .htaccess file is irrelevant here)

And here are my routes. They are in "index.php":

```
<?php

$f3 = require('lib/base.php');

// Routes
require 'controller.php';
$f3->route('GET /index.php', 'Controller->showMain');
$f3->route('GET /', 'Controller->showMain' );
$f3->route('GET /items/@item', 'Controller->showItem');

$f3->run();
```

Any idea what I should look for?

Comment: 1) So what XAMPP has to do here if you are using [PHP's built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) to serve your page? Why not use XAMPP (Apache web server) to serve the whole site in the first place? 2) As far as I'm aware `.htaccess` is not supported by the PHP's web server

Comment: I do not know how F3 works (the routing)... but right now it looks like F3 also handles requests to your .css file; since it has no route defined to handle such files it most likely just sends that "404 Not Found" response. If you want F3 to handle that -- check what URL is requested and use `return false;` for then (i.e. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-426)

Comment: You're right, PHP's web server doesn't manage .htaccess files. It makes sense, it's just the PHP interpreter, it doesn't need a full-fledged web server like Apache. And without a real web server, there's nothing to "serve" the CSS files. I think I got fooled because the RewriteEngine was working. Ok, well I can configure Apache to use a vhost for my project files, but it would be nice to be able to launch from PhpStorm and have access to the PHP debugger.

Comment: *"And without a real web server, there's nothing to "serve" the CSS files."* PHP's web server can do that. Just use `return false;` for such routes (see the link how to do it in a plain PHP) *"...and have access to the PHP debugger"* You can debug any PHP script with PhpStorm regardless of the web server used (Apache/nginx/IIS/whatever) PhpStorm works with Xdebug, and Xdebug gets run as  module/extension of the PHP and not a web server. 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/

Comment: *"but it would be nice to be able to launch from PhpStorm"* Once Apache is running it handles ALL of the virtual hosts -- no need to launch each site separately. If you are about click Run to open URL -- just use Run/Debug Configuration of the appropriate type (that will open the URL for you)

Comment: Resolved! I put the `if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) return false;` line at the beginning of the routing script (index.php in my case) and that resolved the issue. And like you said, the debugger works. Thanks for the help! Do you want to put an answer in so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot you are using [PHP's built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). The thing is: it does not support `.htaccess`. Therefore all HTTP requests go to your router script (`framework/index.php` -- part of the F3 app I guess).

I'm not familiar with how F3 routing works, but I'd assume it's the same as any other: it goes through all registered routes/endpoints and if no match found it will report "404 Not Found" response.

Since there are no rules from `.htaccess` in place to filter out requests for such static/existing files (css/jpg/png/js etc), the request goes through your index.php, through the whole routing table and it's F3 that reports that 404 error back to the browser (when no matching route was found).

There are a few possible solutions here:

1. Create a separate route(s) for such static resources and serve them there from your F3 code (your code needs to locate a file and send a response with the right headers etc.)

   Not really worth implementing it this way TBH (since it's just to handle this specific situation / under PHP's web server).
2. Do a pre-filter and ignore any requests to such static files. When using PHP's web server it's a matter of returning `false` in the router script (which tells PHP to use built-in web server code to serve such request). Look at the sample from the following link and add a similar one to your code: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-426

   ```php
   if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) return false;
   ```

   NOTE: you can add it right into the existing `index.php` like you did (at the top, after all `use` lines but before actual code lines) but this means that you are hardcoding such specific-to-PHP's-web-server-only logic into the script that can run under a proper web server.
   *Instead* I suggest creating a separate router script (e.g. `php-router.php` and use it instead of `index.php` from your screenshot) where you will do this and if execution will pass that condition, only then call the code from your real `index.php` (i.e. `require './index.php';` or alike)

---

Why not use Apache web server from your XAMPP to serve the whole site in the first place?

- Once Apache is running it handles ALL of the virtual hosts (that you can access via fake domain name in your OS' `hosts` file or by having website on a custom dedicated port) -- no need to launch each site separately.
- Apache obviously fully supports `.htaccess` and always better/more features/more close to the production environment than for-dev-only PHP's built-in web server (mod_rewrite and other modules).

Comment: Thanks! Also for the "NOTE" part: You are right to stress that this is a setup for a development environment but not for a production environment. I'll make the adjustment.